Ansible Variable as a command and piped to others
How can i pipe the results of my shell command as a ansible variable to the entire block?
Code:
- name: A 
  shell:
   cmd: |
     /opt/git/bin/cli get service/info/{{ source }}/{{ destination }} | jq -r .secret' 
     /opt/git/bin/user-create '{{ source }}' '{{ password_from_above }}'
     /opt/git/bin/cli set '{{ source }}' '{{ user }}' '{{ user }}' '{{ password_from_above }}'
  vars:
  password_from_above: ??? [Is this needed?]
no_log: true

'/opt/git/bin/cli get service/info/{{ source }}/{{ destination }} | jq -r .secret'
Will output a json where i simply cut out the required password. How can i apply that same password to the next two commands in my shell block?
Does it need to be declared as a variable?
Passing it as a variable fails

you need to save the output of your command in a variable using register and then resue the variable. after shell register a variable register: password_output



- name: Retrieve password and set up user
  shell:
    cmd: |
      password=$( /opt/git/bin/cli get service/info/{{ source }}/{{ destination }} | jq -r .secret )
      /opt/git/bin/user-create '{{ source }}' "$password"
      /opt/git/bin/cli set '{{ source }}' '{{ user }}' '{{ user }}' "$password"
  register: password_output
  no_log: true




name: Retrieve password and set up user
shell:
cmd: |
password=$( /opt/git/bin/cli get service/info/{{ source }}/{{ destination }} | jq -r .secret )
/opt/git/bin/user-create '{{ source }}' "$password"
/opt/git/bin/cli set '{{ source }}' '{{ user }}' '{{ user }}' "$password"
register: password_output
no_log: true

